# Using meta transactions and a smart contract that creates contracts, how can I affect who the contract creator is?

Tags: contract-deployment, meta-transactions, clone

I have a smart contract `RevenueSplitter` which is used to create ERC-721 contracts via a `CollectionFactory` using the minimal proxy pattern.  We recently switched to using meta transactions to initiate contract creation. One unintended side effect of this is that the relayer is now listed as the contract creator for the ERC-721 contract which affects who can manage the contract on OpenSea.

Meta transactions are issued through openzeppelin relayers / auto-tasks and verified by a `Forwarder` contract before calling the `RevenueSplitter` with the encapsulated transaction.

The autotask sends an `Execute` transaction to `Forwarder` contract which then calls `createCollection` on the `RevenueSplitter` contract.  The `RevenueSplitter` then calls `createCollection` on the `CollectionFactory` contract which creates the actual collection using a minimal proxy pattern (OpenZeppelin Clones).

What I would like to accomplish is that the contract creator be the `from` address in the meta transaction rather than the relayer's address.  Is this possible, and if yes, what changes do I need to make?

---

Relevant contracts and transaction:

This is an example of a meta transaction used to create a collection:

https://polygonscan.com/tx/0xac1896b6e72786a581c5f106156bff290323aa5ee80cb36b4e588c835a55e216

The Forwarder is https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0ee7dd0f427077922918ef836d2e80aa7fdcc717

The RevenueSplitter is https://polygonscan.com/address/0xfcd4d3faa3c7d7f1c61e9d1dc8391c96a55675d8

The CollectionFactory is https://polygonscan.com/address/0x27478bdeb95673400207ba78a2cd3973f1064967

The resulting ERC-721 contract is https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa4708ce0adb069ade32854fabb759831b6120b5e

---

Relevant code

Forwarder.execute

```
  function execute(
        ForwardRequest calldata req,
        bytes calldata signature
    ) external payable returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        require(
            verify(req, signature),
            "REMXForwarder: signature does not match request"
        );
        _nonces[req.from] = req.nonce + 1;

        uint256 gasForTransfer = 0;

        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = req.to.call{
            gas: req.gas,
            value: req.value
        }(abi.encodePacked(req.data, req.from));

        require(success, "REMXForwarder: call failed");

        if (gasleft() + gasForTransfer <= req.gas / 63) {
            /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
            assembly {
                invalid()
            }
        }
        return (success, returndata);
    }
```

RevenueSplitter.createCollection

```
    function createCollection(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 royaltyAmount,
        address[] memory _payees,
        uint256[] memory _shares,
        string memory baseURI,
        address minter
    ) external override returns (address) {
        require(
            hasRole(CREATE_COLLECTION_ROLE, _msgSender()) ||
                owner() == _msgSender(),
            "RMX: caller is not owner or collection creator"
        );

        require(bytes(name).length > 5, "RMX: Name too short");
        require(bytes(symbol).length >= 3, "RMX: Symbol too short");
        require(royaltyAmount <= 100, "RMX: Invalid royalty amount");

        address _collection = _collectionFactory.createCollection(
            owner(),
            minter,
            address(this),
            name,
            symbol,
            royaltyAmount,
            baseURI
        );

        _collections[_collection].registered = true;
        _collections[_collection].totalShares = 0;

        emit CreateCollectionEvent(address(_collection));

        _addCollectionPayees(address(_collection), _payees, _shares);

        return address(_collection);
    }
```

CollectionFactory

```
    constructor() {
        implementation = address(new REMXCollection());
    }

    function createCollection(
        address _admin,
        address _minter,
        address revenueSplitter,
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        uint256 royalty,
        string memory baseURI
    ) external override returns (address) {
        address clone = Clones.clone(implementation);
        REMXCollection collection = REMXCollection(payable(clone));
        collection.initialize(
            _admin,
            _minter,
            revenueSplitter,
            name,
            symbol,
            royalty,
            baseURI
        );
        return clone;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer, after consulting several different forums and then thinking deeply about how this works, is that you cannot change the apparent `from` address for a transaction in the way I was thinking.  However, there is a way to fix how OpenSea interprets the ownership of a contract by implementing an `owner` method which, for me, was as simple as adding OpenZeppelin's `Ownable` to our collection contract.  This is, in fact, a better solution in that it allows transferring ownership at a later time if desired!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Biconomy's `BasicMetaTransaction.sol` file . I think that might solve your problem.

Comment: I looked into this, it seems to be using the same basic mechanism that I am already employing.  I am starting to come to the conclusion that this may not be possible.